# In time complexity, is there a meaningful difference between O($2^n$) and O($2^{n/c}$)

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

A table $T$ has $n$ rows and columns, and all the contents of $T$ are of the same data type.

An algorithm chooses a row $r$ and from it successive combinations $c$ of values until the row is no longer needed.  For every $c$ in $r$, the algorithm returns either `true` or `false` in O($c^2$) time.

In general, for every $r$ there are $2^n$ combinations of 1 . . . $n$ values on which to operate.  However, the algorithm will permanently discard the row if the $2^{\lceil n/2 \rceil\textrm{th}}$ $c$ in any $r$ returns `false`.

If I'm calculating this correctly, it means that the time required to discard a single row is O($2^{n/2}$), and since there are $n$ rows, the time required to completely exhaust the table is O($n^{n/2}$).

Is that math correct, and does dividing the $n$ in the exponent by a constant mean that the algorithm completes in polynomial time?

Comment: It's definitely not polynomial time, since $n^{n/2}$ is definitely not $O(n^k)$

Comment: Also, I don't understand the description of your algorithm. Do you mind clarifying what the "discarding row" is doing, or what the algorithm as a whole is doing? For example, you said that "the time required to discard a single row is $O(2^{n/2})$, and since there are $n$ rows, the time required to completely exhaust the table is $O(n^{n/2})$." Shouldn't this be $O(n \cdot 2^{n/2})$ instead? How did you arrive at your answer?

Comment: The algorithm is just looking for two-dimensional patterns in T.  If a row is "exhausted," then it's been proven that none of its data can be part of the pattern, so the row is no longer necessary.  So "discarding" the row is literally deleting it from the table.  On paper, it would be cut out, thrown in the trash, and not revisited.

Comment: I got the answer O($n^{n/2}$) by multiplying $n$ and  $2^{n/2}$ and discarding the contestant coefficient. I thought that's what we're supposed to do in big-O notation, but from your reply I infer that that isn't quite right. Could you please set me right?